# Modern.ie scan saying I need to update jQuery 2.2.0 (latest) to a newer version. :/

Tags: modern.ie

When I scan my site with modern.ie, it says:

> We've found frameworks or libraries that are not up-to-date and might
>   contain bugs.

modern.ie detects that my site is running jQuery 2.2.0 (the latest version).

Is there a bug with the modern.ie site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using?
You can check the current open bugs in its public GitHub repo https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/static-code-scan and open a new issue if you find one

Comment: It's apparently a known issue that already has a pull request waiting to fix it.

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/static-code-scan/issues/107